# Facebook-Unity-SDK Feed Callback Not Called

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

**Problem**
FB.Request() callback parameter is never being called on Android. It works fine on iOS.

**Info**
Unity Version: 4.3.0f4
FB SDK Version: 4.3.6
FB SDK Build Version: 131121.17562b74012d24a

**Repro Steps**

1. Start a new Unity project and import FB SDK 4.3.6
2. Change to an Android project and fill out your keystore info
3. Edit FacebookSettings to match what's in developers.facebook.com in your app
4. Edit InteractiveConsole.cs to add a Debug.Log() on the first line of Callback(FBResult result) (which is the function that should be called when a feed request is done).
5. Build the project with the InteractiveConsole scene
6. Init, Login, and try to post. Notice that your debug log never occurs even though the adb logcat says "“FBUnitySDK( 3272): sending to Unity OnFeedRequestComplete({“id”:”12321312321 blablah”})"

**Details**
We noticed that OnFeedRequestComplete(string message)  in AndroidFacebook.cs, has nothing in it. Also, the callback parameter in FeedRequest(params…) in AndroidFacebook.cs is not being used at all.

Sorry if this is a known-issue but I don't see any similar posts on StackOverflow or on developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: Thanks, we've made a task for this and are looking into it.

Comment: Until this is fixed by Facebook, we were able to make it work by editing a few lines of code in AndroidFacebook.cs.  

I can't figure out how to format a comment so it's not ridiculous in StackOverflow, so you can view the changes here: http://pastebin.com/qJVB3fJc

Not a clean solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out.  I'm getting a fix in for that.  It'll be out for the next update.

Comment: @Brain Jew

Is this fixed yet?

Having the same problem with SDK "FacebookSDK-150414.unitypackage"